# How to downgrade Raring Ringtail back to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, downgrade, 13.04

I've just updated my Ubuntu 12.04 up to Raring Ringtail Daily Build, and now I wanna get back my Precise. I found out that I can't use ATI legacy drivers because of version of kernel and X-Server version. If there is any way to install this driver with Raring, please post me. If there is any way to downgrade kernel, lol, let me know. I just wanna play Team Fortress 2 on my PC with integrated video card, without using noisy HD6850.
Integrated one is Radeon HD4250. Thanks.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE BECAUSE ALL ANSWERS ARE NOT WORKING WITH RARING RINGTAIL.

Comment: Then it is a offtopic, because questions of ubuntu + 1 version are off topic. See here [FAQ]